# Get the time in nanoseconds with actionscript 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Hi I'm trying to get the current time including the nanoseconds in actionscript 3 for use in flex 4.5.
Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what is nanoseconds required for given your application ?

Comment: I need to build an iOS (native) and Android (Flex) client for benchmarking different message formats. And some deserialisation processes on the client take less then 1ms, therefor the duration of that operation seems to take 0ms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ActionScript doesn't expose a timer that precise.

Comment: Would we believe a time alleged to be accurate to the nanosecond by *any* computer? I think not. It would be like measuring days using tree rings.

Comment: @pavium, there are timers that are more accurate than others, regardless of the precise measurement.  ActionScript does not expose any high frequency timer available in many other environments.

Answer (score 9):

The smallest time measure available in Flash Player is milliseconds.

To get current time just create new `Date` object:

```
var currentTime:Date = new Date();
```

See more documentation of `Date` class [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think commont computer don't support smaller time measure then mileseconds

Comment: My iOS client has a function to request nanoseconds

Comment: There are measurements smaller than milliseconds.  Not nanoseconds, but somewhere in between.  For example you can use a Stopwatch in .NET which, depending on OS, will be more precise than a millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if anyone has done this already, but you could create a [Socket](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/Socket.html) interface to an [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) server.

You don't need to implement the whole protocol; you could just do what `ntpdate` does to grab the time.  It has been a very long time since I worked directly with the protocol, but I don't think this task is that hard.

Comment: if he needs nanosecond precision requesting anything over the network feels like the wrong way to go about things.

Comment: Thoughts in head didn't make it into the answer.  I was actually thinking about connecting to a local instance if available.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get nonseconds in Flex, actually there is not much languages out there providing nanoseconds as results into the timespan. The most u could get is "ticks" which is mostly provided for languages with native code execution, but it is not provided directly to a scripting languages.

The best would be to have miliseconds difference, and just scale the result into the benchmark  something like a longer running time ( like 10 or even 100x more tests ) which will bring results much closer to the expecting ones.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to measure something in microseconds I looped it 1000 times and subtracted the time  by the the time the actual for-loop takes. And I would get something close to microseconds.

```
var startTime:int = new Date().valueOf();
for(var ii = 0;ii<1000;ii++)
{
    //do something here     
}
var endTime:int = new Date().valueOf();
trace(endTime-startTime);
```

I guess you can loop 1 000 000 times in order to get nanoseconds but you will have to wait some time for the loop to finish.

Comment: this is pretty wrong as getMilliseconds returns the milliseconds part of the date. Not the total millisecond. It is always between 0.999