# Is there an API to get a more precise time for profiling including operating system?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

In the Flash API there is the getTimer() method that returns the time in milliseconds since the SWF started. I was writing PHP recently and there is a much more precise method called, [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)() that returns the current Unix timestamp in microseconds. Does Flash have anything more precise than getTimer()?

**Update:**
If Flash hasn't yet added a more precise profile API is it possible to use ExternalInterface or make a process call to maybe get an operating system API? I have both desktop and browser applications and in desktop I can access native processes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the time in nanoseconds with actionscript 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175505/get-the-time-in-nanoseconds-with-actionscript-3)

Comment: I've updated the question to include if it is possible to get an external timer and if not why not. The other question does not ask this. Please upvote for friendlyness.

Comment: Going external to the AVM for any things under a millisecond is going to cost you way more time in the interop than you are trying to measure, and even then you have to look at the resolution of the actual time that you are getting. php's microtime is based on the gettimeofday system call and that 'might' have a resolution of 10us. And then you have to deal with multi cpu cores, etc...

Comment: There is CLOCK_MONOTONIC for clock_gettime() that gets around some the gettimeofday issues, but again resolution is an issue. You could write an ANE for Air to access those system calls but would you really get a telemetry based timespan that would mean much in relation to the AVM that is running your AS3 based ABC on a single thread

Comment: Personally doing custom Scout telemetry has also provided enough info (at least for me) I even use items like Scout's Telemetry.sendSpanMetric to profile C#/AS3 within Mono (using the PlayScript AS3->CIL compiler)

Comment: @RobertN is clock_gettime() available from the CLI? I'd like to avoid as much of the middle man as possible (ANE). I'm not sure what latency an ANE would have or calling a native process. Would dual cores mess up a call? If it's possible and the results are consistent then I can factor in those differences. Basically I could time the timer by calling it twice.

Comment: I added an answer with some C code for os-x/linux to get nuances time from the cmd line, Windows users are on their own ;-) http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer is in response to the comment thread*

This is a cli cmd to access the clock_gettime() on Linux and clock_get_time() on OS-X. I use it on OS-X with a couple of bash scripts, but you can call it using [native processes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b060d22f991220f00ad8a-8000.html) with Air

```
>> ./nsTime ; ./nsTime
s:  1446019237
ns: 99241000
s:  1446019237
ns: 104217000
```

Compile:

- OS-X :

  gcc -o nsTime nsTime.c
- Linux:

  gcc -o nsTime nsTime.c -lrt

C Code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __MACH__
#include <mach/clock.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#endif

void current_utc_time(struct timespec *ts) {

#ifdef __MACH__ // OS X does not have clock_gettime, use clock_get_time
  clock_serv_t cclock;
  mach_timespec_t mts;
  host_get_clock_service(mach_host_self(), CALENDAR_CLOCK, &cclock);
  clock_get_time(cclock, &mts);
  mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), cclock);
  ts->tv_sec = mts.tv_sec;
  ts->tv_nsec = mts.tv_nsec;
#else
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ts);
#endif
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct timespec ts;
  current_utc_time(&ts);
  printf("s:  %lu\n", ts.tv_sec);
  printf("ns: %lu\n", ts.tv_nsec);
  return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: This code came from the `Intertubes`, not sure of its original author

Comment: I've never compiled a C program before but I'll give it shot!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jackson Dunstan's sub-millisecond Timer](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/2348) that he wrote about in 2013. I haven't tried it myself, so I can't say if it's any good, but it tries to address your issues with the standard AS3 `Timer`.

Comment: Nice find, I totally forgot about this. Base off of Benjamin Guihaire's getTimer() interation 'hack'...